# Как извлечь только цифры после определенного символа?

Tags: xslt

Есть нод следующего содержания

```
<item is_json_array="yes">
  <name>Дополнительная услуга Количество IP-адресов - 1 Шт (Размещение сервера 1U #817)</name>
  <amount>156.48</amount>
  <taxrate>0</taxrate>
  <taxamount>0.00</taxamount>
  <notaxamount>156.48</notaxamount>
</item>
```

Мне нужно выдрать из `name` подстроку содержащую только цифры после символа `#` т.е. `817` до первого не числового символа либо конца строки. числовых символов может быть произвольное количетсво. xslt 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, проще всего, это сделать так

```
<xsl:template name="extractNum">
  <xsl:param name="str"/>
  <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
  <!-- Получаем строку после разделителя -->
  <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($str, $delimiter)" />
  <!-- все цифры в строке заменяем на 0 -->
  <xsl:variable name="mask" select="translate($tail, '123456789', '000000000')" />
  <xsl:variable name="cnt">
    <!-- считаем, сколько нулей идет в начале строки -->
    <xsl:call-template name="countNum">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$mask"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <!-- вырезаем подстроку, согласно подсчитанному количеству цифр -->
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($tail, 1, $cnt)" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- подсчет количества символов '0' в строке str, начиная с позиции idx -->
<xsl:template name="countNum">
  <xsl:param name="str"/>
  <xsl:param name"idx" select="1"/>
  <!-- получаем символ в текущей позиции -->
  <xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($str, $idx, 1)" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- если это '0' -->
    <xsl:when test="$char = '0'">
      <!-- то вызываем шаблон рекурсивно для следующей позиции -->
      <xsl:call-template name="countNum">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$str"/>
        <xsl:with-param name"idx" select="$idx + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- иначе выводим индекс предыдущего символа -->
      <xsl:value-of select="$idx - 1"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:call-template name="extractNum">
  <xsl:with-param name="str" select="name"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'#'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: спасибо за отклик ! нашел вариант покороче и наверно мне он подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вот такой вариант

```
<xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after(.,'#'),translate(substring-after(.,'#'),'0123456789',''),'')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

[решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119023/how-can-i-extract-only-digits-after-a-certain-character)

Comment: Да, красиво. Единственное замечание вынести `substring-after(.,'#')` в отдельную переменную. И читать будет легче и поддерживать

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov  ок. спасибо!

Comment: Данный вариант не соответствует исходному вопросу. Он вернет **все** цифры после разделителя. А Вы хотели `до первого не числового символа`

Answer (score -2):

Да, в ту самую переменную, которую предложил @Anton Shchyrov, наверно стоит добавить отсечение до первого пробела `substring-before(substring-after(.,'#'), ' ')`

Comment: А также д первой запятой, до первого двоеточия, до первой точки, до первой буквы...